# Is the Teichmuller space of a surface always a contractible CW-complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, moduli-space

I'm trying to prove that the classifying space of the mapping class group of a surface $S$ with genus $g$ and $n$ boundary components is homotopy equivalent to the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$. The easiest proof I can think of is since $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}\cong \textrm{Teich}(g,n)/MCG(g,n)$ the moduli space is necessarily a $K(MCG(g,n),1)$ if Teich$(g,n)$ is a contractible CW-complex.

I certainly know it's true for negative euler characteristic, in which case Teich$(g,n)\cong \mathbb{R}^{6g-6+2n}$. Is it true for general $g$ and $n$ though?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, according to the dimension of the Teichmueller space, it seems you are considering $n$ punctures and not $n$ boundary components. The real dimension of the Teichmueller space of a surface of genus $g$ with $b$ boundary components and $n$ punctures is $6g-6+3b+2n$.

Assuming that you are taking $b=0$ in your case, you need to worry about Euler characteristic zero case, i.e. $2-2g-n=0$, i.e. cases $g=1$, $n=0$, in which case the Teichmueller space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^2$, and $g=0$ and $n=0,1$, in which case the Teichmueller space is trivial. So they are contractible.

There is one issue, though: the mapping class group does not act freely on Teichmueller space. Stabilizers of points are automorphism groups of Riemann surfaces which are finite (in fact, there is a general upper bound given by $84(g-1)$, for closed surfaces), but may be non-trivial. For $(g,n)=(1,0),(2,0)$ the hyperelliptic involution fixes the isotopy class of every simple closed curve and thus fixes all points in Teichmueller space. Similarly, any surface obtained from a hyperelliptic surface of genus 2 by pinching simple curves to punctures, i.e. $(g,n)=(1,2),(1,1),(0,4),(0,3)$ will have a non-trivial stabilizer.
For $g \geq 3$, generically the action is free, but there are examples where the automorphism group is non-trivial (for example, Klein's quartic achieves the maximum order of 168 for an automorphism group of surface genus 3).

So, since the action of $MCG$ has torsion, $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ can't be a $K(G,1)$ space even if $\operatorname{Teich}(g,n)$ is contractible.
There is, however, a finite index non-torsion subgroup $\Gamma \subset MCG$ which allows to make the construction you want, and then you can consider cohomology with rational coefficients to relate the construction to $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$. You can find the details of this construction in Chapter 12 of Primer on Mapping Class Groups, by B. Farb and D. Margalit.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. So you're saying that the moduli space is not the classifying space of $MCG$? This is just surprising to me since Ulrike Tillmann claims it is in her paper 'higher genus surface operad detects infinite loop spaces'. Specifically she says "recall that the moduli space of Riemann surfaces of genus $g$ and $n+1$ boundary components has the homotopy type of $BMCG(g,n)$". Is there something subtle I'm missing there or is it a mistake on Tillmann's part?

Comment: The definition classifying space I'm considering is: $X$ is a $BG$-classifying space if $X$ is the quotient of a weakly contractible space $E$ by a proper and free action of $G$. What I'm saying is that Teichmueller space $\operatorname{Teich(g,n)})$ cannot play the role of $E$ here, because the action of $MCG$ on $\operatorname{Teich(g,n)})$ is not free. You can replace $E$ by another weakly contractible space on which $MCG$ acts freely and properly (there is a canonical construction of an $EG$ space), (continued)

Comment: (continued) but then you cannot expect the corresponding quotient to have the homotopy type of a finite cell complex, because the minimal geometric dimension of a $K(MCG,1)$ is infinite. This follows by results on cohomological dimension of groups: (1) cohomological dimension of $G$ is smaller or equal to the minimal dimension of a $K(G,1)$ complex and (2) the cohomological dimension of a group $G$ with torsion is infinite. (continues)

Comment: (continued) The point is that one can perform a construction which shows that "$\mathcal{M}_g$ is rationally an $MCG$-classifying space". This is stated and explained in section 12.6 of the book Primer on Mapping Class Groups, by Farb and Margalit: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/farbmarg.pdf 
In particular, the claims about group cohomology are referenced there, too.